# Does aria-placeholder attribute applicable for roles other than text box?

Tags: html, css, wai-aria

I am creating a list of custom widgets (say dropdowns and datepicker) by following ARIA standards. Since my custom controls are associated with popup, i.e., when I click on the control, it should open the popup,  I am supposed to use role attribute as combobox or listbox based on the needs. And so I should add aria-haspopup, aria-expanded and so on. Meanwhile, I should add aria-placeholder also. The problem is when I add aria-placeholder, chrome audits test cases fail.

I went through [this](https://www.maxability.co.in/2018/06/05/aria-placeholder-property/) link, where it is stated as aria-placeholder can be used in textbox role. I cannot change the role as textbox, since popup associated attributes (aria-expanded and aria-haspopup) will be failed.

I dont know where and what I am missing. Can anyone explain how to get rid of this? My input would be like this

`<input id="temp" type="text" class="temp-class" name="temp-name" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" aria-haspopup="true" aria-activedescendant="" aria-expanded="false" role="combobox" 
        autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" aria-invalid="false" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0"  placeholder="abcd" aria-placeholder="abcd">`

[image]